# Why does this C program crash? No bugs are reported

Tags: c, crash

So I wrote this piece of code in C and so far this part is supposed to open an image and copy each pixel into an array. At the end I just print to screen one of the pixel values to see if its working. The problem is that the program stops working when I run it and does not report any bugs.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define width 256
#define height 128
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

FILE *fPointer;
int i=0, k=0; //i(height) and k(width) is the loop control variable.
int pixelArray[height][width][3];

fPointer = fopen("image01.red", "r");

for(i=0; i<height; i++){
    for(k=0; k<width; k++){
    fscanf(fPointer, " %d", pixelArray[height][width][1]);
    }
}
fclose(fPointer);
printf(" %d", pixelArray[1][1][1]);
}
```

Also, when I start debugging I get this message: Unhandled exception at 0x5D38DE1B (msvcr110d.dll).

Comment: You can't access `pixelArray[height][width][1]`

Comment: Note that the compiler doesn't report *bugs*. It reports *errors*. There's a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `height` and `width` of your array because it's out of bound. And `fscanf` take a pointer so add an ampersand before your call.

replace this:

```
fscanf(fPointer, " %d", pixelArray[height][width][1]);
```

By:

```
fscanf(fPointer, " %d", &pixelArray[i][k][1]);
```

Comment: Also he should check if the opening of the file succeeded or not!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seemed to have fixed the problem.

Comment: @BartlomiejDanielAdamczyk you're welcome ! don't forget to set the question as resolved !

Answer (score 3):

> No bugs are reported

Compilers report all syntax errors, and some easy-to-detect problems in the logic. C is well known for letting you compile what you think makes sense, and let your code crash if your assumptions are wrong. Therefore, one shouldn't take "it compiles" as a measure of correctness.

In this case, C lets you pass a value where a pointer is required:

```
fscanf(fPointer, " %d", &pixelArray[i][k][1]);
//                      ^
```

`scanf` family of functions always takes pointers - that's the most common way in which C lets a function modify something in the context of the caller. Modern compilers check that, and issue a warning. You should pay attention to all these warnings, treating them like errors.

In this case, the specific warning you would see if you passed the -Wall flag to gcc would be

```
main.c:24:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     fscanf(fPointer, " %d", pixelArray[height][width][1]);
```